# ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted. Selenium Javascript Chromedriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am having problems with clicking an element in a dropdown. What i have to do is:

1. Open https://pastebin.com
2. paste "Hello from WebDriver"
3. Set Paste Expiration to "10 Minutes"
4. Set Paste Title to "helloweb"

However, after opening the dropdown some 3rd party ad content doesn't let me click my button, which results in ElementClickInterceptedError

Here is my code

```
const {Browser} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();

  try {
    await driver.get('https://pastebin.com');
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="postform-text"]')).sendKeys('Hello from WebDriver');
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="w0"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span/span[1]/span')).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-postform-expiration-results\"]/li[3]")).click();
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="postform-name"]')).sendKeys('helloweb');

  finally {
    // await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

The error message im getting:

```
ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted: Element <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-h
aspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-postform-expiration-container">...</span> is not
 clickable at point (301, 605). Other element would receive the click: <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://5c552a9e567bcd9a4394df1b9acbfaaa.safe
frame.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-38/html/container.html" id="google_ads_iframe_/22653346938/12825_Pastebin.com/12825_Pastebin.com_SmartB
anner_1_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="970" height="90" data-is-safeframe="true"
sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" role="r
egion" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" data-google-container-id="3" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-load-complete="true
"></iframe>
```

Comment: > However, after opening the dropdown some 3rd party ad content doesn't let me click my button,

**which button** please clarify ?

Comment: Are you getting error at `await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-postform-expiration-results\"]/li[3]")).click();` here ??

Comment: Is this `xpath`  `//*[@id="select2-postform-expiration-results"]/li[3]` not working ?

Comment: for some reason it is working with no errors this time, but still: i can open the dropdown but cant choose "10 minutes". i think youre right, maybe the xpath is wrong. Can you help me

Comment: Please try this `//option[@value='10M'][contains(.,'10 Minutes')]`

Comment: i tried your suggestion and im getting the same error(i edited it into my post if you wanna see), retried with the xpath i was using before and im getting the error again. i think it depends on the browser and when it decides to put an ad? can you help me

Comment: I have added the answer try that and let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: i replaced both selectors with yours, fisrt time i got the same error, second time it perfectly worked, i tried 2 more times but got the error again. there is an ad at the bottom of the page that's screwing it up, i tried with edge and its just as bad. so your solution is correct but it doesn't always work for my browser

Comment: It could be as you said, but I am not getting any add

Comment: anyways, thank you so much. i was sweating over this problem for days